# How to update all View Holder of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have 6 `ViewHolder` objects.

Currently 4 `ViewHolder` objects are used to display 4 items on screen.

1st `ViewHolder` and the last `ViewHolder` are out of screen.

And now I want to change something inside all the `ViewHolder`. How can I do it?

I know `RecyclerView` has a method: `getChildCount`. But in this case, this method return 4 (because of 4 items on screen). And I want to update all 6 `ViewHolder` objects

Comment: Once your Datasets are changed, calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`; will invalidate all the `ViewHolder`.

Comment: @Enzokie I don't want to recreate all ViewHolder. I just want to change a value inside them. And nothing happens with my dataset.

Comment: Try placing a log in your `onCreateViewHolder()` and use the `notifyDataSetChanged()`. If your log is called meaning the `RecyclerView` creates a new `ViewHolder` but if not then it just re-use the previously created `ViewHolder`.